# Automatically choose file and upload to desired server. How to do this?

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I needed code for automatically chose file and upload it to desired link. How to do that?

**html code:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Uploading</title></head>
<body>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploadFile.php">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>]
```

In above code at this line

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

this path is fixed and can't be changed as user tries. so when user click on "Submit" button the file has to upload.

How to do this?

Comment: OK. Leave this code and is it possible to do this type by other method?

Comment: Also if you *could* do this a user with MAC/LINUX won't have the same path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: **What you are trying to do is absolutely impossible - for a good reason.**

---

If this was possible, you could create a hidden upload field pointing to a file containing valuable data (e.g. the browser's cookie database) and submit the form using JavaScript (or make the user submit it without knowing about that upload) and copy any file the user has access to.

Comment: When we chose file then it shows path, then by fixed path is why not possible?

Comment: Because in that case **the user** chooses the file. Not some possibly malicious site.

Comment: Which part of **it is impossible** did you miss? :)

Comment: As u told above there javascript is required to upload it without knowing about uploaded file.

Comment: No I didn't. I explained **why** it's impossible.

Comment: OK.. is it possible to do this type by other method?

Comment: @user3260468, even a ThiefMaster cannot steal files from the user's file system.

Comment: Yes, it is: By installing malware on the user's system. But of course nobody here will help you with that. ;)

Comment: @haim770 and ThiefMaster I'm not going to steal user file. I'm having problem over uploading a same single file daily. To avoid time wastage I wanted this method. So now I got to know is that this is impossible to do.. Thank you all..

Comment: @user3260468, I didn't really think you want to 'steal' files. But from the browser point of view, it obviously is a 'theft' attempt hence blocked.

Comment: And if it's just for you, why don't you write a small script e.g. in python that runs locally instead of using a webapp?